# Llamar a funcion que tiene como parametros req,res

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Estoy realizando una API en NodeJS con Express, tengo un esquema de productos, al cual genere una función que me permite obtener un producto por su id, la firma de esta función es así:

```
let getProductsById = (req, res) => { ... }
```

A esta función la llamo desde el router en otro archivo así:

```
app.get('/producto/:id', function(req, res) {
    getProductsById(req, res);
});
```

Por ahora nada raro, funciona todo perfecto. Lo que no puedo hacer, es llamar a esa función **getProductsById** desde otro método en este caso uno llamado **addCarrito**, esta tiene una firma de esta forma:

```
let addCarrito = (req, res) => { ... }
```

Lo que estoy tratando de realizar, es dentro de esta llamar a getProductsById de esta forma:

```
carrito.productos.forEach(producto => {
        console.log(producto._id);
        req.params.id = producto._id;
        let productoX = getProductsById(req,res);
    });
```

La función ya esta importada al principio. Pero me tira este error:

```
events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\server\services\productService.js:57:40
    at C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4832:16
    at C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    at C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4855:21
    at C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4407:11
    at C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\node_modules\kareem\index.js:135:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4834:13
    at C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

Alguien me dice que puede estar mal?
Gracias.

Comment: Esto se debe a que en alguna parte de tu código ya estas enviando la respuesta y luego intentas enviarla otra vez cuando esa petición ha sido procesada en teoría. Puedes añadir el código completa para ver exactamente lo que hace la función `getProductsById`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El detalle del error dice que no estás manejando un error de la forma correcta por lo que el [manejador de errores](https://expressjs.com/es/guide/error-handling.html) por defecto de express está tratando ese error y enviando al cliente una respuesta, entonces al querer enviar tu respuesta obtienes el error `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` puesto que express ya ha hecho lo propio. Puedes obtener indicios del error original en `C:\Users\Nacho\Desktop\node\07-restserver\server\services\productService.js:57:40` y ver si existe algún error que estes obviando.